# If I have $\rm CO_2$ near a high electric field, will it get attracted to the electric field?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, polarization, gas

Theoretically speaking if I have some $\rm CO_2$ in a confined environment and I expose it to a high electric field, will it get attracted? For the electric field can I use a Van de graff generator?

Comment: Attracted to what?

Comment: Attached to the electric field pr at least move closer to it

Comment: The field is not an object with a specific location.  The distance between an object and the field is not a thing.